# Stock Market Bot while loop exiting when it should be runnig

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
import schedule
import datetime
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price'
r = requests.get(url).json()

start_price = {'MSFT': 0, 'AAPL': 0,'AMZN': 0,'PYPL': 0,'GOOGL': 0,'TSLA': 0,'FB': 0,'DIS': 0,'TD': 0,'NVDA': 0,'V': 0,'NFLX': 0,'WMT': 0,'ADBE': 0,'CM': 0,'NKE': 0,'DELL': 0,'TWTR': 0,'NSU': 0,'KO': 0}
end_price = {'MSFT': 0, 'AAPL': 0,'AMZN': 0,'PYPL': 0,'GOOGL': 0,'TSLA': 0,'FB': 0,'DIS': 0,'TD': 0,'NVDA': 0,'V': 0,'NFLX': 0,'WMT': 0,'ADBE': 0,'CM': 0,'NKE': 0,'DELL': 0,'TWTR': 0,'NSU': 0,'KO': 0}

def check_stock_price():
    for x in r['stockList']:
        current_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        if current_time[11:16] == '09:30':
            if x['symbol'] == 'MSFT':
                start_price['MSFT'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AAPL':
                start_price['AAPL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AMZN':
                start_price['AMZN'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'PYPL':
                start_price['PYPL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'GOOGL':
                start_price['GOOGL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TSLA':
                start_price['TSLA'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'FB':
                start_price['FB'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DIS':
                start_price['DIS'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TD':
                start_price['TD'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NVDA':
                start_price['NVDA'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'V':
                start_price['V'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NFLX':
                start_price['NFLX'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'WMT':
                start_price['WMT'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'ADBE':
                start_price['ADBE'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'CM':
                start_price['CM'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NKE':
                start_price['NKE'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DELL':
                start_price['DELL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TWTR':
                start_price['TWTR'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NSU':
                start_price['NSU'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'KO':
                start_price['KO'] = (x['price'])
        elif current_time[11:16] == '16:00':
            if x['symbol'] == 'MSFT':
                end_price['MSFT'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AAPL':
                end_price['AAPL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AMZN':
                end_price['AMZN'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'PYPL':
                end_price['PYPL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'GOOGL':
                end_price['GOOGL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TSLA':
                end_price['TSLA'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'FB':
                end_price['FB'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DIS':
                end_price['DIS'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TD':
                end_price['TD'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NVDA':
                end_price['NVDA'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'V':
                end_price['V'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NFLX':
                end_price['NFLX'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'WMT':
                end_price['WMT'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'ADBE':
                end_price['ADBE'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'CM':
                end_price['CM'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NKE':
                end_price['NKE'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DELL':
                end_price['DELL'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TWTR':
                end_price['TWTR'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NSU':
                end_price['NSU'] = (x['price'])
            elif x['symbol'] == 'KO':
                end_price['KO'] = (x['price'])
    print(start_price)
    print(end_price)

schedule.every().day.at("09:30").do(check_stock_price)
schedule.every().day.at("16:00").do(check_stock_price)

start_prices = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
end_prices = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

while True == ((start_prices == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) or (end_prices == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])):
    schedule.run_pending()
    for x in start_price.values():
        start_prices.append(x)
    for y in end_price.values():
        end_prices.append(y)

    time.sleep(1)    

stock = input('Please enter stock NASDAQ name!')
```

Basically my while loop which stops running after I have got the stock prices when the stock market opened and closed doesn't work. I don't see why the while loop is exited when I run the code immediately. When I run the code I get

> 'Please enter stock NASDAQ name!'

which is after the while loop. What I want it to do is to have two dictionaries that I use in the while loop to check if the prices of the stocks are added or not. Until both the starting and the closing prices of all the stocks are there, I want to then terminate the while loop once the prices are there and then ask the user to pick a stock so that my program can then display the price of that stock when the market opened and also when the market closed

Comment: The while loop runs as long as `start_prices` or `end_prices` contain only their initial values.  But the loop also appends new values to both of those lists, so as far as I can see, the while loop will only run once.

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I what it to do! Because I only want to check the prices once a day. But the issue I have is that the while loop exits right when I run it when both start_prices and end_prices are empty, so it should check it once but the while loop just exits. And that's my issue and also what I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call:

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/is-the-market-open

and look for the property : isTheStockMarketOpen

if it is true then you loop.

so if isTheStockMarketOpen is true -> the market is open

They have it in the API.

Comment: I see so basically I didn't even need to use schdule, eh at least I learned it xD. Also I want both when its open and closed so I guess I would need two while loops which one runs until isTheStockMarketOpen is True so that I get the price of when the market opens and also another loop to run until it's false and get the price when it closes.

Comment: And also I think im going to use that instead cuz the current way I do is inefficient and also idk how it doesn't work lol so ty for the answer

Comment: Yes, you can just check if it is True, ping it every x second. if it is False as soon as you see it is close you'll know that the market has closed. Then you don't have to fill the quote. So you will save on ressources.